# What's the equivalent of passing "this" to a function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function which is expecting "this" to be passed as a parameter but I would like to pass a different object without moving the trigger function, so currently I have this:

```
onclick="showCalendarControl(this);"
```

but instead I would like to do this:

```
onclick="showCalendarControl(document.getElementById('somethingelse'));"
```

This doesn't work as it stands, am I trying to do something impossible?

Comment: What does “This doesn't work as it stands” mean, precisely? Error in the console? Something gets / doesn’t get applied to the wrong element?

Comment: can you pass just the string in and let the function handle it?

Comment: what showCalendarControl function do exactly? need to see more code

Comment: You can pass DOM id and search it inside `showCalendarControl` function. What's exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.bind()` function. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

The first argument to `bind` will set the functions' `this` argument (replacing the default one), all other arguments are translated into parameters once the method is called.

Examples:

```
onclick="showCalendarControl.bind(this)"  //the this-statement inside of showCalendarControl will be the specified one

onclick="showCalendarControl.bind(something, this);" //this will be passed as first argument to showCalendarControl
```

---

Edit: After testing it out, it seems that `.bind()` doesn't work in the onclick handler. But your initial idea worked, or at least what I understood as your problem (passing `document.getElementById` result to your method)

```js
function showCalendarControl(obj) {
  obj.innerHTML = "YEY";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="something" onclick="showCalendarControl(document.getElementById('somethingelse'));">Click Me</div>
  <div id="somethingelse"></div>
</body>
```

If you want to bind the parameter to the function's `this` statement, you can try this (use of the [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) function instead of my initial bind):

```js
function showCalendarControl() {
  this.innerHTML = "YEY";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="something" onclick="showCalendarControl.call(document.getElementById('somethingelse'));">Click Me</div>
  <div id="somethingelse"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: How do you know that `showCalendarControl` accepts more than one parameter?

Comment: In javascript, all methods accept variable input length. Its just a matter of reading it or not

Comment: Sure, and how do you know that `showCalendarControl` reads a second parameter? I could not have found any hint on that in the question.

Comment: @gus27 oh. i just thought that showCalendarControl was his own function, and if so, hes free to manipulate it as he wants. Doesn't look like a library method imo